# Hide/show function is not working for fileupload resourceType in AEM

Tags: aem-touch-ui

I was implementing the hide/show functionality for a Touch UI dialog in AEM 6.3, before there was a pathbrowser to render the image but now i have updated that with a fileupload as a resourceType.
The existing functionality of hide/show which was working fine with pathbrowser is not working only for fileupload resourceType now.
Any quick answers for the above query is appreciated.

Thanks,
Arunmozhi

Answer (score 0):

please try to use wrapper node like 'fieldset'.

```
<showHideWrapper 
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
class="hide showHideWrapper-showhide-target"
showhidetargetvalue="OPAQUE">
<items 
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    .... there is your fileUpload field 

</items>
</showHideWrapper>
```